# Handling file explorer in C# How to change to "All Files" option

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I'm trying to handle a file explorer in C# but I don't know how to select the "All Files" option
[image]

I've been successful in typing a file path into the file name text box and I'm able to press the OK button. But I can't select the file if I can't filter by "All Files"

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\email\Desktop\Hardware Hub\images\" + ID + ".png");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to generate "Custom Files" and "All Files" ? What happens when you click "All Files" ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use SendKeys. You use the FileName property to populate the input field and use the FilterIndex property to select "All Files" on your OpenFileDialog instance.

```
var fileContent = string.Empty;
var filePath = string.Empty;

using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog.FileName = "Your filename"; // Sets the file name input
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2; // Sets filter to 'All Files'
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Get the path of specified file
        filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

        //Read the contents of the file into a stream
        var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(fileContent, "File Content at path: " + filePath, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```